# Multiple ConfigurationElement types in ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: .net, app-config

I would like to have a configuration section like the following:

```
<mycollection>
 <add name="myelement" type="class, assembly" var1="value" var2="value" />
 <add name="myelement2" type="class2, assembly" var1="value" var3="value" var4="value" />
</mycollection>
```

The idea being that the actual `ConfigurationElement` created is defined by the type value, and that each element will have its own specific set of attributes.

Another option would be that all the elements are the same, but they load the values from a different configuration section, e.g.:

```
<mycollection>
 <add name="myelement" configuration="myothersection" />
 <add name="myelement2" configuration="myothersection2" />
</mycollection>

<myothersection type="class, assembly" var1="value" var2="value" />
```

This seems easier to implement but leads to more verbose configuration file.

Is the first option respecting the .NET configuration pattern, and secondly, is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible! Check out this post for details: [http://code.dblock.org/2009/02/18/nesting-multiple-configurationelement-types-in-a-configurationelementcollection.html](http://code.dblock.org/2009/02/18/nesting-multiple-configurationelement-types-in-a-configurationelementcollection.html) Along the same lines here a solution that allows you to read extremely flexible xml using IConfigurationSectionHandler: [http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Craig/XmlSerializerSectionHandler.html](https://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/clr-workings/the-last-configuration-section-h

Answer (score 3):

Something else you could do is override [OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.ondeserializeunrecognizedelement.aspx). This way you could create a ParametersConfigurationElement like this:

```
<parameters>
  <string name="Patrick Huizinga" />
  <string country="the Netherlands" />
  <int currentScore="206" />
</parameters>
```

The OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement takes an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) that you can inquire about the attributes of the custom element. By using [TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hceyy41f.aspx) (you can get a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) from [TypeDescriptor.GetConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx.aspx)) you can even support types like DateTime and Uri without any extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

From [Adding collections to a custom ConfigurationSection](https://blog.dezfowler.com/2011/01/adding-collections-to-custom.html)
Such .config

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="mySpecialSection" type="MyNamespace.MySpecialConfigurationSection, MyAssembly"/>
</configSections>
...
<mySpecialSection>
 <items>
  <apple value="one"/>
  <apple value="two"/>
  <orange value="one"/>
 </items>
</mySpecialSection>
```

can be achieved with code

```cs
public class MySpecialConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
 [ConfigurationProperty("items", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false, IsDefaultCollection = false)]
 public ItemCollection Items
 {
  get { return ((ItemCollection) (base["items"])); }
  set { base["items"] = value; }
 }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Item), AddItemName = "apple,orange", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMapAlternate)]
public class ItemCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
 public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
 {
  get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMapAlternate; }
 }

 protected override string ElementName
 {
  get { return string.Empty; }
 }

 protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
 {
  return (elementName == "apple" || elementName == "orange");
 }

 protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
 {
  return element;
 }

 protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
 {
  return new Item();
 }

 protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement(string elementName)
 {
  var item = new Item();
  if (elementName == "apple")
  {
   item.Type = ItemType.Apple;
  }
  else if(elementName == "orange")
  {
   item.Type = ItemType.Orange;
  }
  return item;
 }

 public override bool IsReadOnly()
 {
  return false;
 }
}

public enum ItemType
{
 Apple,
 Orange
}

public class Item
{
 public ItemType Type { get; set; }

 [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
 public string Value
 {
  get { return (string)base["value"]; }
  set { base["value"] = value; }
 }
}
```

> [Adding collections to a custom ConfigurationSection](https://blog.dezfowler.com/2011/01/adding-collections-to-custom.html)
> Notice that here we've specified two collection items with the value "one" which would have resulted in one overwriting the other in the previous example. To get around this, instead of returning the `Value` property we're returning the element itself as the unique key.
>
> This time our `ConfigurationElementCollection` derived type's `ConfigurationCollection` attribute also specifies a comma delimited `AddItemName` e.g. `"allow,deny"`. We override the methods of the base as follows:
>
> - Override `ElementName` to return empty string
> - Override `IsElementName` to return true when encountering a correct element name
> - Override `GetNewElement()` to new up an instance of your item type
> - Override `GetNewElement(elementName)` to new up an instance of the correct item type for particular element name setting relevant properties
> - Override `GetElementKey(element)` to return an object which uniquely identifies the item. This could be a property value, a combination of values as some hash or the element itself